# How to increase the frequency of useragent’s progress event?

Tags: superagent

By default, the `progress` event is only fired once a second.

```js
import request from "superagent"
const req = request.post("https://example.net")
// files.forEach((file) => {
//   req.attach(file.name, file)
// })
req.on("progress", (event) => {
  console.log(event.percent) // This is only fired once a second
})
req.end()
```